# Laravel 5.6 Eager Loading specific column returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two classes, `Product` and `ProductFormat`. The relationship is defined properly, my Product `hasMany` ProductFormat.

```
public function formats()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductFormat::class);
}
```

When I'm trying to eager load the relationship with specific columns, as followed in the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), it's not working as expected.

For example, when I do the following:

```
Product::with('formats:id,upc')->get();
```

I get my products, with empty formats everywhere.

```
{
    id: 1,
    formats: [ ]
}
```

However, if I do the following:

```
Product::with('formats')->get();
```

I get the expected formats, but it has too many non needed columns.

```
{
    id: 1,
    formats: [
        {
            id: 1,
            upc: "101862422191",
            weight: 8.46,
            weight_unit: "kg"
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a product_id field on the product_format table?

Comment: @Mkk Yes I do, I can fetch the relationship properly with `$product->formats`.

Comment: I think this behaviour is intender to single object relations, like in the docs `$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();` is a `belongsTo()` relation, you are using a `hasMany()`, that may be it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You always need foreign key/primary key, involved in the relation, to be selected. fetch product_id too in eager load and it will work

```
Product::with('formats:id,upc,product_id')->get();
```

Comment: I guess you need the foreign key when fetching a `HasMany` relationship. I don't need it when I fetch a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: This would have been more helpful if it was mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: This is the correct answer! It makes no sense to be forced to fetch the parent key in every single child record... especially since you already have it in the parent. I will bring up with the Laravel team. I totally agree the documentation should be fixed for hasMany() relations.

Comment: I've created pull request to add this to the documentation!

Comment: it's already in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading read heading => Eager Loading Specific Columns

Comment: @UsmanJdn it's in 5.8 doc but not in lower version doc (missing for 5.5, 5.6, 5.7)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem so i had to write my query this way. You will need to retrieve the ID of the foreign Key unless you get a `null` value from the relationship

```
Transaction::with([
    'client' => function($query){
        $query->select('id', 'first_name');
    }
])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but i solved it by the following way:

```
// Change this in model 
public function formats()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductFormat::class)->select(['id', 'upc']); 
}

// No need to join here. 
$data = Product::all();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value->formats);
}
```

By this you will get the required format.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific columns in Eager load, there are 2 methods:

Method 1 :
in your `ProductFormat` model, set `protected $visible = ['col_1,'col_2'];`

Method 2:

use the `closure` that accept `Builder $query` as an argument.

```
Product::with(['format' => function ($query) {     
$query->select('col_1', 'col_2'); 
})->get();
```