# Eager Loading specific column with joining in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I don't want to load all columns from score_set but id only. I tried this code was fail.

```
Assignment::with('score_set:id.scoringCriteria.fields:id')->whereIn('id',  $assignment_id)->get();
```

it show sql error.
**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id.scoringCriteria.fields' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`.`scoringCriteria`.`fields` from `score_sets` where `score_sets`.`id` in (1) and `score_sets`.`deleted_at` is null)**

Comment: Are `scoringCriteria` and `fields`  nested relations of `score_set`?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045457/laravel-5-6-eager-loading-specific-column-returns-nothing.